# Computer over current detected

Tags: memory, graphics-card, cpu, motherboard, power-supply

Hello so I’ve had my pc for 5 years no problem. The build is as follows: mobo is ASUS H81M-PLUS, CPU is intel 4790k, GPU is Zotac 960 4gb AMP!, ram is 16gb(8x2)of Corsair xms3 DDR3 and PSU is EVGA 650 GQ.

I was on the computer gaming when it shutdown like there was a power cut but nothing else had switched off just the pc. Pressing the on button doesn’t do anything.
I took the graphics card out and unplugged the hardrive and the case USB ports, I took the motherboard out of the case and tried to boot from there. It booted but I was greeted with the attached screen. The pc would trim off after a few seconds. I assumed it was a broken motherboard as I couldn’t find any damage to the case ports.
I ordered the same motherboard and put the cpu and ram in, and connected everything but the graphics card, hardrive and case ports. In its current state with the new motherboard it turns on but I can’t get any signal to my monitor it’s like the ports on the new motherboard aren’t working.
It’s also worth to note that any time I put the graphics card back in the mobo it fails to turn on. Sorry if it’s not detailed enough ask any question and I will try to answer with detail. The screen I get when it boots.

[image]

Comment: "USB Device over current status detected" usually means that a USB device was shut down because of an overloading circuit, to protect your hardware from damage. You may need to change the USB ports, and/or the PSU (because this is apparently a power problem). Might it not be more economical to replace the computer?

Comment: I’ve replaced the motherboard so there shouldn’t be any problems with the usb devices now, my problem now is that when I boot the pc up I don’t get any signal on my monitor and my keyboard lights won’t go on. In its current state it can stay powered on but no signal to the monitor. Plugging in the gpu causes the pc to not turn on could this be because the psu isn’t supplying enough power?

Comment: Yes, that's the next possibility if the USB ports are new.